# Kubernetes deployment created but not listed

Tags: kubernetes

I've just started learning Kubernetes and I have created the deployment using the command `kubectl run demo1-k8s --image=demo1-k8s:1.0 --port 8080 --image-pull-policy=Never`. I got the message that deployment get created. But when I listed the deployment (`kubectl get deployments`), deployments not listed instead and I got the message `No resources found in default namespace.`

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) `kubectl run` creates a pod and not deployment. So you can use `kubectl get pods` command to check if the pod is created or not. For creating deployment use `kubectl create deployment` as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-deployment-em-)

Answer (score 0):

for deployment creation you need to use `kubectl create deployment`. with `kubectl run` a pod will be created.

```
kubectl create deployment demo1-k8s  --image=demo1-k8s:1.0
```

the template is like `kubectl create deployment <deployment-name> --<flags>`

but it's always better if you use `yaml` to create deployment or other k8s resource. just create a `.yaml` file.

**deploy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo1-k8s
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo1-k8s
  replicas: 4 # Update the replicas from 2 to 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo1-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo1-k8s
        image: demo1-k8s:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

run this command `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`